# What is the difference between "gradle" and "gradle plugin"?

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-plugin

What is the difference between Android "gradle" and "gradle plugin"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/what_is_gradle.html) is an open-source build automation tool that is designed to be flexible enough to build almost any type of software, including Android apps, for example.

Gradle at its core intentionally provides very little for real world automation. All of the useful features, like the ability to compile Java code, are added by [plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html). Plugins add new tasks (e.g. `JavaCompile`), domain objects (e.g. `SourceSet`), conventions (e.g. Java source is located at `src/main/java`) as well as extending core objects and objects from other plugins.

Answer (score 2):

[Gradle](https://gradle.org/guides/#getting-started) is the build system.

You can use it with [a lot of plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html). One of this is the [plugin for Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html).
It is used to provide processes and configurable settings that are **specific** to building and testing **Android** applications.